# Split display in two column with bootstrap and thymleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I use thymeleaf and bootstrap 3 and I create ui component in function of a list.

I don't know how many items are in the list.

```
<form id="genericForm"  class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div th:each="userForm : ${usersForm}" class="form-group">
        <label th:attr="for='userForm'+${userForm.field}" class="col-sm-2 control-label" th:text="#{${userForm.i18n}}"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" th:id="'userForm'+${userForm.field}" th:attr="name=${userForm.field}"/>
            </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

Each ui component is displayed one below the other.

Is there a way to display in two column?

Comment: Take a look to the [thymeleaf loop](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) As an idea, you can use the special thymleaf iteration variable inside the each block and display in the proper div (one for even other for odd)

Comment: You want to display in 2 columns the full div with class form-group? or the label in one column and next div in other column?